# Need help opening and closing a horizontal slide out panel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I have a code to open a slideout panel using css but I need help finding a way to close it as well. Here is the code:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $('#slideout').toggleClass('on');
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#slideout {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: -520px;
  width: 500px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
#slideout form {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
}
#slideout textarea {
  display:block;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  width: 250px;
}
#slideout.on {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CSS Slide Out Panel</title>
    
    
    
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    
    
    
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="Slidecontainer">
  
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Toggle</button>

  <div id="slideout">
    <form>
      <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Post feedback"></input>
    </form>
  </div>

</div>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

        <script src="js/index.js"></script>

    
    
    
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the way it looks now:
[Without Close Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVZN7.png)

And this is the way i'd like it to look:
[With Close Fuction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suPOg.png)

Comment: Clicking on the button should remove the .on class and close it too, no?

Answer (score 1):

Try following way. Remove `on` class from `slideout`.

**Edit:**

You can do using separate button also. Using `addClass` on Open button.

```js
$('.closebtn').click(function(){
  $('#slideout').removeClass('on');
});

$('.openbtn').click(function(){
  $('#slideout').addClass('on');
});

$('.btn-default').click(function(){
  $('#slideout').toggleClass('on');
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#slideout {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: -520px;
  width: 500px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
#slideout form {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
}
#slideout textarea {
  display:block;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  width: 250px;
}
#slideout.on {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CSS Slide Out Panel</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="Slidecontainer">
  
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Toggle</button>
<button type="button" class="openbtn">Open</button>

<div id="slideout">
    <form>
      <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Post feedback"></input>
      <button type="button" class="closebtn">Close</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
  
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way I'd be able to do this with simple linked text instead of buttons?

Comment: @E.B. Yes. `<a href="#" class="openbtn">Open</a>` instead of button. same way for close

Comment: What about having the panel slide out from the right side instead of the left?

Comment: @E.B. For that you should ask new question.